# High load of resources by software RAID1 in Debian 6

Tags: linux, debian, raid

I have a server with Debian 6 and software RAID1. There is a problem: every few seconds the jbd2/md2-8 process loads all the HDD IO. It was detected by iotop. And for the md2_raid1 process 99% of IO displays.

The flush-9:2 process every few seconds loads 99% of CPU in top.

What can I do to optimize this system? Can transition to hardware RAID help in this situation?

This is cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md3 : active raid1 sda4[0] sdb4[1]
      1822442815 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      1073740664 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      524276 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      33553336 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Yes, transitioning to hardware RAID would help the situation.

Comment: have the same problem, my disks seem to be ok, I checked them with smartctl. It is really strange because the box becomes unresponsive

Answer (score 1):

next time this happens, run the following command "cat /proc/mdstat" then paste the output here

Comment: I have pasted it in main text

Comment: Hello, sorry that I had never responded, was looking around just now, and it seems that something called noflushd can cause issues like what you are describing. Check out this article to see what I am talking about http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/99-cpu-usage-due-to-flush-8-0-and-flush-8-16-a-822553/

Answer (score 0):

Your software raid is taking all the CPU cycles in order to run the RAID.  Getting a hardware RAID can help.  Keep in mind that if you want to take full advantage of a RAID controller you will need to ensure it has a BBU (battery back up) in order to enable the cache and write-back mode.

Depending on what is important to you, you could turn on RAID 0 (striping) and get even better performance out of your system, but even a regular RAID hardware controller will help.